# How to loop through a 3d matrix with a single loop?

Tags: algorithm, loops, multidimensional-array

a matrix made from 2 dimensions is as follows:

```
for (i = 0; i <length*length; i++)
    Mat [i/length, i% length] = i;
```

so how do I loop through a 3d matrix?

```
for (i = 0; i <length*length*length; i++)
    Mat [?] = i;
```

Comment: How do you do it by hand?  (Hint: write out the sequence of indices for e.g. a 3x3x3 array.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write *index* in base *length*, and you will get general solution for N dimesions.

So, for 3D it will be

```
for (i = 0; i <length*length*length; i++)
     p = i;
     z = p % length;

     p /= length;
     y = p % length;

     p /= length;
     x = p;
     Mat [x, y, z] = i;
```

Or just shorter

```
for (i = 0; i <length*length*length; i++)
     Mat[i / (length*length), (i/length) % length, i % length] = i
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 0; i <length*length*length; i++)
    q = i/(length*length);
    r = i%(length*length);
    Mat [q, r/length, r%length] = i;
```

**Python**

```
k = 3

for i in xrange(k * k * k):
    q = i / (k * k)
    r = i % (k * k)
    print q, r / k, r % k
```

**Ouput**

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 0 2
0 1 0
0 1 1
0 1 2
0 2 0
0 2 1
0 2 2
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 0 2
1 1 0
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 2 0
1 2 1
1 2 2
2 0 0
2 0 1
2 0 2
2 1 0
2 1 1
2 1 2
2 2 0
2 2 1
2 2 2
```

Comment: @OliCharlesworth you're right. my bad. now it should be fine.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth you sure?

Comment: Ah apologies, I hadn't noticed that the 2nd coordinate was being calculated as a combination of `r = i%(length*length)` **and** `r/length`.